# Ability to only view (not edit) other user's personal profile information

Tags: customization, profiles, capabilities, user-roles

I have created 2 roles, `Center` and `Student`, for my WordPress website with different capabilities using members plugin.

I want the student role users to be only able to view and edit their personal profile information and I achieved this by granting them the read capability.

Now the issue is I want the Center role users to be able to list and view student role users personal profile information without being able to edit them.

I have granted the Center role three capabilities: `read`, `list_users`, `edit_users`
with this I am able to list all users as I wanted to, I am able to view personal profile information but with the ability to edit.

I know that with `edit_users` editing ability will come, but I want to know how to limit it to view or ready only, or is there any other way out.

I don't want the Center users to be able to edit student users personal information, they should just be able to list and view the information.

I am new to WordPress and I am loving it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do one of the following things;

- Create a separate page and only display the data (seems to me the best approach)
- Display the information on `user-edit.php` and create a hook telling WP that if the user role is `Center` and is trying to save other user information return an error.

It actually depends on your WP knowledge and time you are whiling to invest.